# How can I create DateTime object based on the day?

Tags: ruby

I want to create an Datetime object based on the number of day in the year.
This number is from the 365 days of the year (for example it can be: 123 or 23 or 344...)

How can I do that?

Thanks

Comment: Is it from the start of the year or from the current day you want it?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the [DateTime.ordinal](http://www.ruby-doc.org/stdlib/libdoc/date/rdoc/classes/DateTime.html#M000481) method. Here's an example to get the 100th day of year 2011.

```
require 'date'
year, day = 2011, 100
DateTime.ordinal(year, day)
# #<DateTime: 2011-04-10T00:00:00+00:00 (4911323/2,0,2299161)>
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want it as the number of days from now you should do the following:

```
time = Time.new + (60*60*24)*(numberOfDaysFromNow)
```

If you want it as the number of days from the start of the year you should do the following

```
time = Time.new(Time.now.year) + (60*60*24)*(dayOfTheYear-1)
```